# Using features extracted using a pretrained CNN as new features for an CNN/NN

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am extracting features from pictures using a pretrained CNN. Would it make sense to use those features as inputs for a new CNN/NN? Has it been done before? I would be very happy to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *finetuning*. It is very commonly used. Usually, one deletes the last few layers of a VGG or a similar network, adds layers which suit to the task and trains the network on the new data.

See:

- https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/issues/218
- http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read about finetuning, but for some reason I did not make the connection to what I described above. Is there any particular advantage of using finetuning vs. using the CNN for feature extraction and training a SVM for the classification?

Comment: Reasons to use a pure CNN model instead of a mixed CNN / SVM model: (1) Speed / accuracy, when there are many classes (2) simplicity: why should you use two models, when you can use only one? (3) end-to-end training: it makes more sense to have one model where you can know that there are no conflicting objectives. However, as so often: Just try it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try both :)

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/image_retraining/) even shows you how to do it trivially with tensorflow without writing any line of code. It is very useful when you have visual data but you have very few samples.

I successfully used it to get results much better than my classmates in a project, since whatever architecture they tried they just didn't have enough data. It takes about 1h to use if you have used tensorflow before, one afternoon if you haven't and you run into software problems.